# Autodesk Inventor cannot install b/c it is installed

Tags: windows-10, autodesk-inventor

Recently, I uninstalled Autodesk Inventor 2016, but when I tried to reinstall the program, it claims that it is already installed and will not let me install the program. However, the program is non-existent on my computer and I also followed instructions to delete all the registry files.

Anyone know a workaround for this?

---

*One of the solutions mentioned using the Microsoft "Fix-it" tool, but the website doesn't allow me to run the program, nor can I find it on windows 10.

Comment: You can't find the Fix-it because it doesn't support Windows.  What instructions did you follow exactly?  I assume you have contacted Autodesk support?

Comment: @Ramhound these instructions: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/installation-activation-licensing/get-ready/remove-products/clean-uninstall

Answer (score 1):

You can find detailed steps here for manual uninstall:

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/customer-service/installation-activation-licensing/get-ready/remove-products/clean-uninstall

There is also an uninstall tool provided by Autodesk. You should find it in your start menu (All applications, Autodesk folder). If it is not there, you should find it in your install package, in x64\VE\PFiles\CommFiles\Autodesk Shared\Uninstall Tool\R1\

Comment: This was one of the first places I looked to solve the problem. I have already followed all the steps and used the uninstall tool, but the installer still claims the product is installed.